# Failed to add Table Adapter, Specified Cast is not valid Error

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

I created added a Dataset to my vb.net project. Now  I am trying to add a table to the dataset but it is failing giving the following Error Message[image]

Below is my table definiton:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rep_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rep_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rep_DOB` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rep_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `rep_phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rep_email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `rep_position` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `co_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `branch` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `co_address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `co_telephone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `co_email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `co_fax` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Can Someone assist me to solve this issue, I am Using mysql Workbench and mysql database. I am using mysql for visual studio 1.2.6 and mysql connector 6.9.8

Comment: MySQL is a bit of a pain in the neck with tableadapters, but I'm sure it can be worked around. Post the definition of your table, and the version of your mysql connector (and confirm which one it is - COnnector/Net? ODBC?) and the version of the db

Comment: I am using connector/net